# What is the difference between wp_siteurl and wp_homeurl in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

What is the difference between `wp_siteurl` and `wp_homeurl` in WordPress? And what is the meaning of these lines given below:

```php
/* Handle multi domain into single instance of wordpress installation*/

 define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
 define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: This may answer your question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50605/69743

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Home URL:** The WP_HOME constant corresponds to the WordPress Address (URL) input field in the Admin. It is used to determine the result of the home_url API function.

The Home URL is the URL you want your visitors to enter to reach your blog. If you wish to have a blog at /musings, then the WP_HOME should be `http://example.com/musings`

**Site URL:** The WP_SITEURL constant corresponds to the Site Address (URL) input field in the Admin. And it is used to determine the result of the site_url API function.

The Site URL must point to the path to your WordPress installation. If you have installed WordPress in a subdirectory like /wordpress then this path must be `http://example.com/wordpress.`